# Simulator bug where SF Symbols are not showing up in UIKit (but work in SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, ios-simulator, sf-symbols

I'm running into a very bizarre bug in the iOS Simulator, see title.

On first run of a new Simulator instance, the SF Symbol(s) appear for both SwiftUI and UIKit, but then after restarting the app and/or the Simulator instance, they no longer do for UIKit views only.

I can't figure out why this is happening and the only workaround is to delete that Simulator instance and recreate it.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: If you are using a simulator with the latest SDK of Xcode, try checking if the issue is present in previous versions of iOS

Comment: Yeah it shows up in 15.5 and 16.4 alike in the Simulator. It's super weird.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to use SF Symbols then you can use it through code

```
UIImage(systemName: "star")
```

And you can watch out for all the SF symbols by SF Symbols [Icon](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/)

Comment: As mentioned, this does not work.